# Angular ionic Open email app using cordova app-launcher

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic angular application
for mobile devices, on button click, I want to launch the mail app using the plugin
https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-app-launcher

<ion-button shape="round" (click)="openEmailApp()">
how to use this app launcher

Answer (score 0):

This plugin also provide a example https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-app-launcher#3-usage .

```
openEmailApp(){
            window.plugins.launcher.launch({packageName:'com.google.android.gm'}).then(success, failure);
    }
```